# Difference between Glassfish server local and remote commands?

Tags: glassfish

I am not able to understand the difference between Glassfish server local and remote commands. The link given at

[1]: http://weblogs.java.net/blog/kalali/archive/2010/04/25/learning-glassfish-v3-command-line-administration-interface-cli says this:

> Local commands are a set of commands which either affects the
>   environment which application server is running or it needs accessing
>   the application server environment locally to execute some scripts or
>   batch files to perform a job.
>
> In the Opposite side of the local commands we have remote commands
>   which form a set of commands that affects the running application
>   server instance configuration and access the application server
>   environment and file system using an application deployed in the
>   application server itself. Therefore the target instance should be
>   running and there should be a network route between the administration
>   workstation and the GlassFish instance running on the server machine.

I suppose I have two machines viz machine A and machine B. I have a Glassfish running on machine B. Can I use `asadmin` on machine A to connect with Glassfish running on machine B and perform any local or remote command?

Answer (score 1):

It's simple:

A "remote" command is any command that is given to a running Glassfish Server.
A "local" command is a command that is NOT given to a running GlassFish server.

A simple and obvious example is the command to start a domain.  Clearly at that point there *is* no running GlassFish server.  It must be a local command.

Important points

1. All remote commands communicate using a host and port.
2. Local commands only run on the current machine.  It is impossible to use asadmin to directly run a local command on a different machine (there is nothing for it to communicate with).
3. Running a remote command on the current machine or a machine 10,000 miles away is exactly the same as far as asadmin is concerned.  It just uses a different host address.

To run a remote command on a different machine simply specify the host with the --host option.